# Ajax, PHP, MySQL Not updating server or webapge

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with my AJAX and MySQL/PHP script.

The first file below, is my javascript file I use to test accessing my server. This file works as far as I know and have tested.

```
Game = function() {};

var timer;
Game.EncodeURI = function (text) {
    return encodeURIComponent(text);
}

Game.DecodeURI = function (text) {
return decodeURIComponent(text);
}
Game.AlterDiv = function(div,data) {
if (Game.ID(div)) {
    Game.ID(div).innerHTML = data;
}
   }
Game.ID = function(value) {
return document.getElementById(value);
}
 Game.ServerRequest = function (url, data) {
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
    }   
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            data = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");                 
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var one = Game.DecodeURI(data[parseInt(i)]);
                    var two = Game.DecodeURI(data[parseInt(i) + 1]);
                    var three = Game.DecodeURI(data[parseInt(i) + 2]);
                    var four = Game.DecodeURI(data[parseInt(i) + 3]);
                    var five = Game.DecodeURI(data[parseInt(i) + 4]);
                }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (!data) {
        data = "";
    }
    data = data.replace(/: /gi, "=");
    data = data.replace(/:/gi, "=");
    data = data.replace(/, /gi, "&");
    data = data.replace(/,/gi, "&");


xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(data);
 }
Game.Action = function (id, seconds) {
clearTimeout(timer);

    if (id) {
        if (!seconds) {
            Game.AlterDiv('message', 'You begin working.');
            Game.ServerRequest("action.php", "id: " + id);  
        } else {        
            Game.AlterDiv('message', 'You begin working.');
            Game.ID('timer').innerHTML = seconds;   

                    if (seconds >= 2) {
                        seconds -= 1;
                        Game.ID('timer').innerHTML = seconds;           
                        timer = setTimeout(function(){          
                                Game.Action(id, seconds);                       
                            },1000);
                    } else { 
                        Game.ID('timer').innerHTML = "Finished";
                        Game.ServerRequest("action.php", "id: " + id + ", x: x");   // Request it, then POST "x" to say timer has counted down.
                    }
        }
    } else {
        alert("There was an error with your request.\n Please try again.");
    }
}
```

This second file is a basic PHP web page that I use to test the said function.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<span onClick="Game.Action('1','5');">Start Work</span><br /><br />


<div id="message"></div>

<div id="timer"></div>


</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js?<?php echo time(); ?>"></script><!-- the time() stops it cache-ing -->
```

This third file is my PHP/MYSQL file that I use to connect to the database.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "gurstang");

$id = $_POST['id'];

if(isset($_POST['x'])) {
$x = true;
}else{
$x = false;
}
$userid = 1;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `action_info` WHERE `actionid` = '$id'";
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $action_name = $row['name'];
    $basetimer = $row['time'];
    $gaineditem = $row['itemid'];
}
$result->free();
}
$query = "SELECT `item`,`plural` FROM `items` WHERE `itemid` = '$gaineditem' LIMIT 0,1";
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $gained_item = $row['item'];
    $gained_plural = $row['plural'];
    }
    $result->free();
}

if($x == false){
echo "Action|$id|"5"";
$message = "You have begun working.";
echo "AlterDiv|message|$message";

}
if($x == true){
echo "Action|$id|"5"";

$itemnumber = mt_rand(1,2);
$gainedmessage = "You have gained $itemnumner $gained_item.";
echo "AlterDiv|message|$gainedmessage";
$query = "SELECT `count` FROM inventory WHERE userid = '$userid' AND itemid = '$gaineditem' LIMIT 0,1";

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $count = $row['count'];
        $add = $count + $itemnumber;

        $updatequery = "UPDATE `inventory` SET `count` = '$add' WHERE `userid` = '$userid' AND `itemid` = '$gaineditem'";
        $mysqli->query($updatequery);
    }
    }
    else{
        $insertquery = "INSERT INTO `inventory` (`userid`, `itemid` ,`count`) VALUES ('$userid', '$gaineditem', '1')";
        $mysqli->query($insertquery);  
    }
}
?>
```

Those are all 3 of the file currently to run my script. I have an onclick event in the php webpage, and it sends the values to my Javascript function of Game.Action. After testing I have concluded or at least assume that my Javascript function for Game.Action works. After testing my Game.ServerRequest function, I have concluded that there is a change somewhere happening. Although, when I check my server to see if the updates actually happened, nothing happens. It doesn't update the timer div or the message div properly.

So basically my question is, is my issue with PHP/MYSQL or AJAX?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you give us more info.

Comment: Did you try poblating the $_POST array manually with known values to test if the PHP script works as expected?

Comment: @Class More info involving?

Comment: @arraintxo There are known values in the server that it should be retrieving and updating. But I haven't tried populating the array manually. As far as I can see the mysql queries should work, I almost copied them straight from my registration/login scripts.

Comment: Try this: make a new php script page and just return an echo of anything.  In your ajax post, call back the data that is being retrieved from that script.  If you are reading your echo then you can tell that your ajax -> PHP is working.  Once you know that is working, start debugging your php script IN your database (go into your mySQL admin section and manually write the script you want) This will help you make sure (or not) that your php -> MySQL is working.  If your mySQL query works, then your php is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @ntgCleaner It seems the issue lies with my Ajax -> PHP.